# Domain Independent Cluster on AWS

Tags: sql-server, clustering, aws, dns, windows-server

I am trying to work out whether it's possible to create a Domain Independent Workgroup Cluster in AWS (on Windows Server 2016 for use with SQL 2017 Availability Groups). This environment also has no DNS server, so I would need to manually create entries in the host file of each node for each resource. However, I believe for AWS clusters the nodes need to reside in different subnets, and each node needs its own dedicated IP address for the WSFC resource?

Does anyone know if this actually possible in AWS without a DNS server? If so, what would the host file entries need to be for the WSFC resource on each node? In a regular single subnet cluster I believe this would be the same IP for both nodes, but when each node has its own IP for the WSFC resource I'm not sure if this will work?

Example config is as follows:

---

**Cluster Name - TestCluster1**

---

**Node1**

> Subnet - 192.168.0.0/24
>
> Primary IP - 192.168.0.1
>
> WSFC IP - 192.168.0.2

Host File Entries:

> 192.168.1.1 Node2
>
> ??????????? TestCluster1

---

**Node2**

> Subnet - 192.168.1.0/24
>
> Primary IP - 192.168.1.1
>
> WSFC IP - 192.168.1.2

Host File Entries:

> 192.168.0.1 Node1
>
> ??????????? TestCluster1

---

Any thoughts welcome!

Thanks

---

**EDIT:** As a follow-up to this, I have tried adding host file entries for both WSFC IPs on each node as follows:

> 192.168.0.2 TestCluster1
>
> 192.168.1.2 TestCluster1

After a quick test it appears this does seem to work - I presume it simulates a round-robin DNS approach, although I don't know how advisable it is?!

Comment: Cluster less and without AD SQL server always on is possible. You can try this out. https://www.sqlgossip.com/sql-server-availability-group-without-cluster-in-windows/

Comment: I didn't know that was possible! Thanks, that's very useful!